Periodic writes while reading large amount of data
I have a large number of image files (~220,000) stored on a fast, local SSD. Using python and the tifffile library I read the images in as numpy arrays, which are then combined into a single array and saved to disk. Reading this combined array is much faster than separately reading the files.
I'm trying to understand why there are writes (upwards of 30 MB/s) happening during the reading of the data (Expected: all reads happen, then a combined array is created, then one write happens). There's clearly more than enough RAM available while this is happening (the entire dataset fits in RAM):

I assume there's data still available in memory (but not marked as using memory) to explain why the first ~15 GB is loaded without incurring any disk reads (reading starts near the left-side of the plot).
A basic code example is something like this:
import os
import numpy as np
from tifffile import imread
from functools import partial
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map

def get_image(dir, ID):
    # Load as a numpy array
    return imread(os.path.join(dir, ID + ".tif"))
    
def generate_numpy_file(IDs, folder, fname="train"):
    _read = partial(get_image, folder)

    print("Reading Data")
    images = process_map(_read, IDs, max_workers=20, chunksize=1024)
    images = np.array(images)

    print("Writing Data")
    np.save(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, "Datasets", fname), images)


If this is not the first time you've run this, it's possible that some of the image files are still in the filesystem cache.  Windows will use up to half your RAM to buffer previously read files.  Remember that the operating system has to update the "last access time" in the directory when you read a file.

Good point. Given the large chunk size the pattern of write spikes could make sense from updating metadata periodically.

It seems you simply have a case where all lazy-operations in Python and numpy internals are working as planned.  process_map returns a generator, and np.array(...) call simply doesn't consume it eagerly, instead, requesting each item from images as it is needed in the write operation - and the np.save operation just does the same - retrieving each item lazily as it goes writing.
If you need all reading to take place first, then some operation after images = np.array(images) is needed so that everything will be loaded into the memory. I did some tests here, and it looks like it is tifflib itself which allows the subprocess task to return early, while still having the OS fetching the data files - maybe even as a "side-effect", as it is  not documented - but that code is concurrency intensive (example of what is executed within a .imread) call), and it could "leak laziness".  (np.array  + tqdm...process_map won't provide the lazyness by themselves)  -I see no other way for the writting to take place concurrently with the reading there.
Despite things happening concurrently in this job, your job is likely still loading everything into the memory, because the lazy images array should retain data after its contents are consumed by np.save - so if your goals would be to improve memory usage a more complicated adjust would have to be made there.

To clarify: it looks like the file on disk is not modified until the call to np.save, at which point there is a large spike in disk usage, as expected. Did your testing reveal something different?
